# How to remove spaces between words using regular expression in sublime text?

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have some values look like these:

```
$lang['Delivery Charge'] = 'Delivery Charge';

$lang['Frequently Asked Questions'] = 'Frequently Asked Questions';
```

I am using this regular expression to select the variable index:

`\$lang\['.*'\]`

Now how can I replace the spaces between words for only the variable indexes not in values.

I mean my final result will look like:

```
$lang['DeliveryCharge'] = 'Delivery Charge';

$lang['FrequentlyAskedQuestions'] = 'Frequently Asked Questions';
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
(?:\$\w+\['|\G(?!^))\w+\K\h+
```

*Explanation*

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\$\w+\['` Match `$` and 1+ word chars and `['`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close non capture group
- `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
- `\K\h+` Reset the match buffer and match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars

And replace with an empty string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MklFI6/1)

To also check for a closing `]` , where there can not be square brackets in between, you could add a positive lookahead:

```
(?:\$\w+\['|\G(?!^))\w+\K\h+(?=[^][]*'])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AFJzrF/1)

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks. I have tested it in Sublime 3.2.2 and for that version it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot and lot, this works and saved my lot of time

Comment: @JvdV Thanks a lot for guiding me, I did what you guided.

Comment: @Thefourthbird can you please write me a regex for this lang('Add Area') for the same purpose?

Comment: @NazmulHasanNero You could use the same mechanism https://regex101.com/r/lINvkl/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks a lot, I got it